# New with Cocoapods, keep getting errors after installing

Tags: cocoapods

this is the first time i am doing this, but after following the instructions online for cocoa pods it seems like I can't use it after installing. Can someone please help?

```
Ronalds-Air:~ ronaldm$ gem install cocoapods --user-install
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/ronaldm in PATH, mode 040707
Fetching: cocoapods-1.0.1.gem (100%)
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/ronaldm/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin in your PATH,
  gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.0.1
1 gem installed
```

and then I tried this way

```
Ronalds-Air:~ ronaldm$ /Users/ronaldm/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/pod install
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/ronaldm in PATH, mode 040707
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

and I tried sudo but that didn't help, any help would be ver much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error won't stop you from adding dependencies to your iOS, but it will stop you from being able run any gem executables.

Add the following line at the bottom of your ~/.bash_profile (or create it, if it doesn't exist)

```
export PATH="~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin:$PATH"
```